# Ember - Querying model by properties in a related model

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm trying query my post model for published posts that have a specific tag. My models look like this:

```
var Post = DS.Model.extend({
    tags: DS.hasMany('tag', { async: true }),
    title: DS.attr('string'),
    published: DS.attr('boolean'),
});

var Tag = DS.Model.extend({
    posts: DS.hasMany('post', { async: true }),
    name: DS.attr('string')
});
```

I've been able to get published posts in my query using the `find()` method:

```
this.get('store').find('post', {published: true});
```

But I don't understand how to query for properties that are part of a related model. I'd appreciate any guidance, thanks!

---

### Edit

I came up with this solution using `filter()` which seems to work well.

```
var self = this;
var store = this.get('store');

store.find('post', {published: true}).then(function() {
    self.set('content', store.filter('post', function(post) {
        return post.get('tag.name') === 'Photography';
    }));
});
```